# Angular material drag and drop reset to initial position when click reset button

Tags: javascript, angular

Move the div to the initial position when click on hte close button.

```
<div style="background: red; width:75px" class="example-box" (cdkDragEnded)="drop($event)" cdkDrag>
  <button (click)="reset()">close</button>
  Contents of dragable element
</div>
```

ts file

```
distance = {};
  drop(ev): void {
    console.log('element dropped');
    this.distance = ev.distance;
    console.log(ev);
  }
  reset() {
    console.log('Moved to initial position', this.distance)
  }
```

Here dragging is happaning, but I need to reset the initial position while click the close button

Answer (score 3):

**Angular material reset the drag position**

```
evt;
  drop(ev): void {
    this.evt = ev.source;
  }
  reset() {
    this.evt._dragRef.reset();
  }
```

Comment: What if there is no event?  How do you reset this from pure code without a cdkDrag event firing?